# Xero - Getting 401 Unauthorized for get:/Accounts, scopes added

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to get a list of my accounts using
GET:**https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Accounts** with my access token.

The response is 401 / Unauthorized

My app has these scopes:

```
accounting.transactions
accounting.transactions.read
accounting.settings
accounting.settings.read
accounting.contacts
accounting.contacts.read
```

**accounting.settings.read** should be adequate according to the [Scopes documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/scopes/#organisation-scopes)

I am using the same PHP code used to GET:/Invoices which works fine, with headers:

```
Accept: application/json
authorization: Bearer $access_token
```

I am using a **Custom Connection**, as we have a machine-to-machine setup with no interface.

The App configuration screen, and available scopes are shown here:

[image: screenshot of Xero Custom Connection app configuration screen]

[image: Full list of available scopes within my Xero Custom Connection app]

Comment: Do you also have `offline_access` and `openid` in your scope? I have what you have, those two, and `email` in mine, for a similar scenario, but not using a Custom Connection. Is that the new monthly-paid connection type?

Comment: @droopsnoot none of `offline_access`, `openid` or `email` are options in the scopes list. And yes it's the monthly-paid custom connection type

Comment: Ah, sorry, can't help then, that's a different connection type to the one I'm using. The doc suggests that `accounting.settings` is the one you need, and you have it. My only other suggestion is contact the API support team and see if they can look at your API call from their end and see what the problem is.

Comment: @droopsnoot FWIW I raised it with Xero support and having gone through several attempts for them they have now said they will raise it with the Xero developers. So I think it is in fact a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the update.